# How can i remove key's from json doc array in nodeJS

Tags: json, node.js

Is there a quick and stable way to remove all a key value pair from a json Doc array. In my case i have data returned from my DB which contains more fields then i want to show to user so i want to query my db and see what key's he is supposed to get before returning the json to client.
In this sample the data has 3 keys, FirstName,LastName and dob how would i go to remove all dob Key and values from the json, also if i have to remove more then one Key Value pair does it make difference when you do it ?

```
{
"result":[
   {
       "FirstName": "Test1",
       "LastName":  "User",
       "dob":  "01/01/2011"
   },
   {
       "FirstName": "user",
       "LastName":  "user",
       "dob":  "01/01/2017"
   },
   {
       "FirstName": "Ropbert",
       "LastName":  "Jones",
       "dob":  "01/01/2001"
   },
   {
       "FirstName": "hitesh",
       "LastName":  "prajapti",
       "dob":  "01/01/2010"
   }
```

]
}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove a property from a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-do-i-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) operator on the obj while looping through your data.

```js
let data = {
  "result": [{
      "FirstName": "Test1",
      "LastName": "User",
      "dob": "01/01/2011"
    },
    {
      "FirstName": "user",
      "LastName": "user",
      "dob": "01/01/2017"
    },
    {
      "FirstName": "Ropbert",
      "LastName": "Jones",
      "dob": "01/01/2001"
    },
    {
      "FirstName": "hitesh",
      "LastName": "prajapti",
      "dob": "01/01/2010"
    }
  ]
}

// @param keys: an array of keys to remove
function removeKeyValue(obj, keys) {
  obj.forEach(currObj => {
    keys.forEach(key => {
      delete currObj[key];
    });
  });
}

removeKeyValue(data.result, ["dob", "LastName"]);
console.log(data.result);
```

Comment: Thanks, any chance to remove more then 1 KeyValue at time or would i have to loop over the loop ?

Comment: @MisterniceGuy I updated the example to take multiple keys to delete. Loop through the keys to delete for each obj.